# error "application non installée" When I want to upload a new update to my app

Tags: android

I have a app in 'Google play store'. I want to upload a new update to my app .

When I finished the new version of the application, I tried to install it on the phone over the old version but I get the error message `application not installed`.

I used the same package name and same keystore

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens because of the build is not packaged properly. It happened with me when i was using JNI. If Clean, invalidate cache and rebuild is not working then please share more details about the app which libraries and features you are using like progurd, jni or something else.